# What are these names - ' name of my God' and 'my new name' Jesus mentions in Rev:3:12?

Tags: jesus, revelation, names-of-god

Revelation 3:12 (KJV):

> "Him that overcometh will I make a pillar in the temple of my God, and he shall go no more out: and I will write upon him the **name of my God,** and the name of the city of my God, which is new Jerusalem, which cometh down out of heaven from my God: and I will write upon him **my new name."**

Here, the name of the "city of my God" is clear - it's New Jerusalem.

But, what are the other names Jesus mentions here - the 'name of my God' and 'My new name'?

Comment: Actually, given that the Greek has "*the* new Jerusalem" (with a definite article rather than the KJV's participle "which is") I would say it is clearer that it is not the actual name but a description.

Comment: Doesn't the use of the definite article sometimes imply personhood? I mean a proper noun? IE. A name.?

Comment: Related:  http://dailydoseofgreek.com/?s=revelation+3%3A12

Comment: The name of my God is not the New Jerusalem, it was the name of the city of My God  that was identified

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Bible commentaries](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/revelation/3-12.htm) that I have read, the first 2 names are simple. The "name of my God" would be the unspoken name of Yahveh, the second as you pointed out is already spoken of in the scripture itself, "New Jerusalem". However the third name is the new name for Christ himself.

> The last of the triple inscriptions declares that the victor shall be conspicuously Christ’s. ‘I will write upon him My new name.’ All the three inscriptions link themselves, not with earlier, but with later parts of this most artistically constructed book of the Revelation; and in a subsequent portion of it we read of a new name of Christ’s, which no man knoweth save Himself. "What is that new name? It is an expression for the sum of the new revelations of what He is, which will flood the souls of the redeemed when they pass from earth.

The three names written on the believers represents ownership, and to whom these ones belong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all of these names represent the new revelation given to the overcoming saints as part of their reward. Each name is tied to a new revelation. Peter was part of a new revelation Jesus gave to Simon. Abram to Abraham represented a new covenant and new revelation to Abram/Abraham. I personally believe they will reveal the new relationship of "bride of Christ" and how that relates to God the Father and to Jesus Christ. We will take on this new name as part of our new relationship.

Comment: "I believe" is not usually a good way to start an answer, as we are looking for in depth analysis, not just opinions.  Can you cite some references to back your position or more thoroughly explain how you got it from the text itself? Please note that "showing your work" is [required](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/735/what-kind-of-site-do-we-ultimately-want-to-have/777#777) on this Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

The word translated multiple times in Rev 3:12 as "name" (ὄνομα) would in my ever so humble opinion better be translated as "title" or "handle".

> YLT Rev 3: 12He who is overcoming—I will make him a pillar in the
>   sanctuary of my God, and without he may not go any more, and I will
>   write upon him the name [ὄνομα] of my God, and the name [ὄνομα] of the
>   city of my God, the new Jerusalem, that doth come down out of the
>   heaven from my God—also my new name [ὄνομα].
>
> Young, R. (1997). Young’s Literal Translation (Re 3:12). Bellingham,
>   WA: Logos Bible Software.

This is a reference to the fact that in the OT God was referred to by the Tetragrammaton and "the LORD" while the post-resurrection title for God is "the God and father of our lord Jesus the Christ," or "the Father" for short and Jesus is now called "the lord".

The Father:

> BSB
>
> 2 Cor 1: 2Grace and peace to you from God our Father and the Lord
>   Jesus Christ. 3Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ,
>   the Father of compassion and the God of all comfort,
>
> Ephesians 1:3 Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ,
>   who has blessed us in Christ with every spiritual blessing in the
>   heavenly realms.
>
> Colossians 1:3 We always thank God, the Father of our Lord Jesus
>   Christ, when we pray for you,
>
> 1 Peter 1:3 Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ! By
>   His great mercy, He has given us new birth into a living hope through
>   the resurrection of Jesus Christ from the dead,

And Jesus, the post-resurrection son of God and lord (his new title):

> Heb 1: 4 So he became as much superior to the angels **as the name he
>   has inherited is superior to theirs.** 5 For to which of the angels
>   did God ever say, “You are my **Son**; today **I have become your
>   Father**” ? Or again, “**I will be his Father, and he will be my
>   Son**” ?
>
> New International Version Acts 2:36 "Therefore let all Israel be
>   assured of this: **God has made this Jesus, whom you crucified, both
>   Lord and Messiah."**
>
> BSB Philippians 2: 9Therefore **God exalted Him to the highest place,
>   and gave Him the name [title] above all names**, 10that at the name
>   [title] of Jesus every knee should bow, in heaven and on earth and
>   under the earth, 11and every tongue confess that **Jesus Christ is
>   Lord**, to the glory of **God the Father**.…

Comment: NRSVA Revelation 19:12 " His eyes are like a flame of fire, and on his head are many diadems; and he has a name inscribed that no one knows but himself."   This verse and Philippians 2:9 mentioned above are the two verses which make reference to the  "unknown name" so I believe the question will never be answered.